# Buying Campingaz in Eastern Europe

Tags: camping, cooking, fuel

My boyfriend and I are currently a month into a 3-4 month trip in Europe and are finding it quite challenging to find suitable gas refills for our van. The gas runs both the cooktop and the fridge. 
 We have a [Campingaz R907](https://www.campingaz.com/uk/p-23531-r-907.aspx) cylinder and are out of gas in Poland, en route to Romania, Bulgaria and Montenegro where we plan to spend most of the next 2 months. We will pass through the eastern parts of Slovakia and Hungary today/tomorrow.

We were under the impression that Campingaz was easily available throughout Europe, but that doesn’t seem to be in case in any of the countries we plan to be in in the immediate future. We are wondering what our options are as 
Is it possible to:

- buy a different brand of gas cylinder that will fit the regulator we have (15mm screw in)?
- change the regulator to one that is going to be more conducive to the gas cylinders that are available in the countries we are heading to? If this is possible, can we do this ourselves? Can anyone suggest names of stores from which we could buy the required equipment please?

Comment: Is the burner made by campingaz? if so, it might be calibrated to burn efficiently with a mix that should be 80% butane, 20% propane. If you can't refill with the same mix and only find 100% propane, there *could be* combustion issues where more harmful byproducts are released in your camper.

Comment: Welcome Boucledor! Thanks for coming here with your important and detailed question! I edited it by splitting it up into paragraphs to make it easier to read. I hope you find what you need!

Comment: isn't it refillable, though?

Answer (score 4):

Your bottle will just contain [LPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquefied_petroleum_gas). The problem you may have is the connector for filling up. This is non standard across countries and so you may require an adapter.

adapters: https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/gas-cylinder-adapter.html

stations in romania: https://www.mylpg.eu/stations/romania/

how to refill: https://youtu.be/eyRwM2WJm6I

more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYjFiJbfxWg

Answer (score 2):

I was able to refill my CampingGaz 907 bottle at the INA in Tivat. They have a filling factory behind the petrol station: https://goo.gl/maps/cis2zcHGFoSNzLzd8

I went to lots of other places and most people had no idea what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Camping Gaz store locator for Poland: http://www.campingaz.com/PL/t-retailerlocator.aspx. It might help (and you can use Google Translate if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but we have already looked on that website. The stores that pop up for Poland only sell the canisters, not the bottles.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for an overview of cylinder connections per country: https://www.4ever2wherever.com/gas/

Comment: Can you please copy and paste a relevant part of the information on that website into this answer? That is because links often go bad and also because people should not have to follow a link to see whether it is information they can use.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/17280)